# How to convert AAC byte stream to PCM in UWP

Tags: windows, uwp, c++-cx, pcm, aac

How to convert AAC byte stream to PCM before playing in UWP since [AudioGraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.audio.audiograph#Windows_Media_Audio_AudioGraph_CreateAsync_Windows_Media_Audio_AudioGraphSettings_) - CreateFrameInputNode encoding properties accepts only PCM. How to play AAC byte stream in UWP using AudioGraph?

Comment: Why do you believe, that the AudioGraph would support a single input node type only? And why do you believe, that you need to call `CreateFrameInputNode` anyway? Like your previous questions (now deleted), this question looks like you have misanalyzed your problem, and now need help with a solution that isn't. Please take the time to *properly* analyze your problem. Keep in mind that a constant stream of low-quality questions will get your account temporarily suspended from posting new questions.

Comment: CreateFrameInputNode is called to provide audio data via frameInputNode->AddFrame(audioData) method.

Comment: I thought we have to convert AAC byte stream to PCM before playing it in UWP. After looking in Media​Stream​Source class I understood there is no need for conversion. Solved the issue by supplying AAC data to [Media​Stream​Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediastreamsource). Used MediaPlayer to play Media​Stream​Sample data.